# Dynamic Hyperlink in SQL Server Reporting Services SSRS 2005. Expression not resolving field?

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, hyperlink, expression, reportingservices-2005

SSRS 2005.

Added a textbox> Properties> Navigation> jump to URL > Entered the URL, but can't seem to add dataset fields that resolve??

I tried inserting the Field via report builder dataset with no luck resulting in this:

https://mydomain.com?ID=(I need my field here)

https://mydomain.com?ID=First(Fields!ows_ID.Value,"ContractSummary")

turns into this which fails for me.

https://mydomain.com?ID=First(Fields!ows_ID.Value,%20%22ContractSummary%22)

instead of this where I know ows_ID is 27:

https://mydomain.com?ID=27

**UPDATE: I tried this and it works from Report builder client, but when deployed to SharePoint the link is just a textbox that does not work:

="https://mysite.com?ID="&Fields!ows_ID.Value**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try activating it through javascript:

```
="javascript:void(window.top.location.href='https://mysite.com?ID=" + CStr(Fields!ows_ID.Value) + "')"
```

Comment: thanks that worked and I used it. sorry about delay in accepting.